# Changing the class of divs in a pattern using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, algebra

I have a blog layout I'm working on (bootstrap) and I've hit a snag.

I need the first two divs to be col-md-3 (NORMAL), then the following 2 divs col-md-6 (WIDE), then it needs to make the next 4 divs as col-md-3 (NORMAL), then the next 2 divs col-md-6(WIDE) and so on, so forth.

I've tried [this method in codepen][1], which works (code below) but is obviously not the most efficient way to do it - I'm fairly new to jQuery, so would appreciate any help you can offer!

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="blog">
    <div>Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery used:

```
$("#blog div").each(function(i) {
var newClass = 'col-md-3 red';
if (i == 2) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 3) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 8) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 9) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 14) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 15) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 20) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 21) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 26) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 27) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 32) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
if (i == 33) newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
$(this).addClass(newClass);
});
```

Comment: The pattern you describe in your question doesn't seem to match what's in your code. It appears from your `html` that you want your `div`s to follow this pattern: Normal, Wide, Wide, Normal, Normal, Normal. There are six elements in this pattern and you want it repeated until you've exhausted all the divs in your `#blog div`. Is that an accurate summary of what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `.not()` and `.filter()`

```js
$('#blog div').addClass('col-md-3 red')         // add red class to all the divs
  .not(':lt(2)')                                // exclude the first two Normal elements
  .filter(function(i){                          // filter to get the Wide elements
    return (i % 6 == 0) || ( (i % 6) - 1 == 0)  // filter every 6 element and the element next of it
  }).addClass('col-md-6 blue');                 // add the class to the Wide elements
```

```css
.red{
  background : red;
}
.blue{
  background : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="blog">
    <div>Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Epic, Thank you so much - this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that iterates through each of the `div`s and selects the appropriate class based on its position in a `pattern` array. It's not a heck of a lot more compact than what you've already got *BUT* it has the significant advantage of not requiring you to manually fix your `JavaScript` if you change the number of `div`s or the pattern itself. Using this approach you can simply change the items in the `pattern` array and get a different result immediately.

```js
elements = $("#blog").children();
pattern = ['col-md-3','col-md-3',
          'col-md-6','col-md-6',
          'col-md-3', 'col-md-3'];
  pattern_val = 0;
  for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    if (pattern_val < 6) {
      $(elements[i]).addClass(pattern[pattern_val]);
      pattern_val += 1;
    }
    else {
      pattern_val = 0;
      $(elements[i]).addClass(pattern[pattern_val]);
      pattern_val += 1;
    }
};
```

Here's a [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/jamestollefson/pen/MWePjpd) of it in action.

Answer (score 0):

use the `text` method to get the content of the current element.

```
$("#blog div").each(function(i) {
    var newClass = 'col-md-3 red';
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text == "Wide") {
        newClass = 'col-md-6 blue';
    }
    $(this).addClass(newClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And this decision is from me. Objects and keys are involved here. Each object (class) is assigned corresponding keys (index).

```js
let obj = {
  "col-md-3": [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 35, 36],
  "col-md-6": [3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16, 21, 22, 27, 28, 33, 34]
}

let objKeys = Object.keys(obj),
    objValues = Object.values(obj);

let nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#blog div");

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {            
    let index = objValues.findIndex(id => id.indexOf(i + 1) > -1)
    
    if (index > -1) {
        nodes[i].classList.add(objKeys[index]);
    }
}

$(nodes).each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass(obj[i]);
});
```

```css
.col-md-3, 
.col-md-6 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="blog">
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Wide</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
    <div class="">Normal</div>
  </div>
</div>
```